# How to calculate the permutation of a bit vector?

Tags: algorithm, permutation

Given a bit vector V = (101101), and a permutation function: F(x) = (a*x + b) mod p. Where a and b are random numbers and p is a prime number. How can I calculate the permutation of the vector V? Does F(x) take V as an entire value or should I use each bit in V as a x for the function?

Comment: What's your context? Is the bit vector representing a number in binary?

Comment: @greyfairer No it's just a bit vector

Comment: Permutation on a bit vector using that function doesn't make sense to me. It would make sense if it was a permutation matrix multiplication or something...

Comment: Usually scalar multiplication / addition with a vector means multiplying / adding the number with / to each element, but this won't really make sense when talking about binary. If `a` and `b` were vectors as well, it could make sense. If I were to guess, I'd say you should treat the bit vector as the number the bits represent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in order to permute the bit vector, then take each bit and apply the permutation function on it.

[image: An introduction to permutation functions]

Answer (score 1):

In that definition, the permutation function gives the new position for each entry in the vector. E.g. for a=2, b=0, p=7, the function gives {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}->{0,2,4,6,1,3,5}.

Using this function, any vector of 7 elements can be permuted, transforming {a,b,c,d,e,f,g} into {a,c,e,g,b,d,f}.

This only works if the size of the vector is equal to the prime p. So for a bit vector move each element at position n to position a*n+b mod p.

This also works for non-prime number p, as long as a and b are co-prime with p.